# Does a single atomic operation marked as std::memory_order_seq_cst trigger sequential consistency everywhere?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

Sequential consistency imposes a global order of all atomic operations on all threads. As far as I know, this means that threads will behave as specified in the source code, with no reordering. All threads will execute their operations in a sequential order.

Intuitively, it looks like an option or a flag to set in the `main()` function of your multithreaded app, something like "I want all my threads to follow sequential consistency". Of course there's no such thing in C++.

So here's my question: is the sole presence of a single `x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` or `x.store(y, std::memory_order_seq_cst)` instruction anywhere in the code enough to force ALL threads, even those unrelated to `x` to behave in a sequentially consistent way?

Comment: Looking at small `1)` and `2)` taken from : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering -> `as soon as atomic operations that are not tagged memory_order_seq_cst enter the picture, the sequential consistency is lost`, I'd say no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `memory_order_seq_cst` only guarantees that there is a total order of all `memory_order_seq_cst` atomic accesses/fences, see [[atomics.order]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/atomics.order#3) of the C++17 standard final draft. It does not impose that requirement on other memory accesses, even on atomic accesses with weaker memory orders.

For example if, for two atomic variables `std::atomic<int> x{0}, y{0};` initialized with `0`, thread 1 executes

```
x.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

and thread 2 executes

```
y.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

while thread 3 and 4 execute

```
auto a = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
auto b = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

then thread 3 could e.g. observe `a == 1` and `b == 0`, while thread 4 observes `a == 0` and `b == 1`. `y` is not accessed with any `memory_order_seq_cst` operation and is not sequenced with the `x` store. Therefore there is no single inter-thread ordering determining the order in which the stores on `x` and `y` happen.

There is also a note to that effect in the C++17 standard final draft, section [[atomics.order]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/atomics.order#8).

Comment: OK very interesting. Say you change the first load into `auto a = x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);`: the sequential consistency is now guaranteed only around operations performed on `x` by thread 1, 3, 4 and not across all threads. Is this correct? If so, isn't this a sort of acquire/release semantics?

Comment: @Ignorant Changing the `x.load` to `memory_order_seq_cst` and all other `memory_order_relaxed` operations in the example to `memory_order_acq_rel`  does not change the potential results. Acquire/release does not imply any order between *different* atomic variables (as long as the accesses are not in the same thread).

Comment: @walnut "_Acquire/release does not imply any order between different atomic variables_" yes, not for pure loads and pure stores "_(as long as the accesses are not in the same thread)._" acq and rel work for diff threads communicating with rel->acq, exactly like for the same thread. Your comment is slightly misleading.

Comment: @curiousguy My comment may be misleading, since I didn't really manage to express what I want to say in a comment. The point was that acq/rel on the same atomic imposes memory ordering on the threads in which acq/rel of the variable happen, but not (by itself) on other threads with acq/rel operations on other atomics, contrary to seq_cst. Of course memory ordering on accesses around the acq/rel impose further ordering, that may in the end propagate to an ordering requirement on the unrelated atomics, but that is not automatic.

Comment: E.g. in my example here acq_rel is not enough to force a single inter-thread ordering between the two stores. I hope I got that right, otherwise please correct me.

Comment: @walnut "**acq_rel** _is not enough to force a single inter-thread ordering between the two stores_" Careful! The stores are only rel, by definition: they don't even "read" the previous value, so you wouldn't be able to specify acq semantics for them, as it's defined in term of value read (even if later ignored). Missing acq semantic, they don't pull history and don't create global history. Only atomic (mutexed, either a priori or a posteriori) acq-rel operations guarantee that in general. Understanding the difference between an ordinary atomic op and a RMW is essential: only RMW are acq+rel.

Comment: @walnut "_but not (by itself) on other threads with acq/rel operations on other atomics, contrary to seq_cst_" What exactly do you believe atomic seq_cst operations guarantee when threads X1, X2... act on shared atomics a1, a2... and threads Y1, Y2... act on shared atomics b1, b2...? IOW what use of seq_cst on atomics guarantee memory ordering that wouldn't be guaranteed by acq_rel?

Comment: @curiousguy To your first comment: Yes that is what had in mind. I used `acq_rel` as short-hand for `acq` on atomic loads and `rel` on atomic stores and both on RMW.  Here I was referring to `rel` on the two stores in the example and `acq` on the loads in the other threads. To your second comment: My understanding is that with only rel, two additional threads `Z1, Z2` can observe the store order between the `a_n` and `b_n` atomics in different orders as long as the `a_n`s are still ordered and the `b_n`s are. This is not the case with seq_cst.